# SQL How to find carts that only contain specific cart items?

Tags: sql

Lets say I have two tables, table cart and cart_item. A cart can have one or more cart_items.

Cart_items are "templated" from an items table. Attributes like item_name will be the same for multiple cart_items. I would like to create a query that returns all carts (all cart attributes not just id) containing cart_items named Apple **AND** Banana **AND** Carrot.

Following is a couple examples I've tried.

```
Table cart 
cart_id_pk
cart_desc
cart_total
etc...

Table cart_item
item_id
item_name
cart_id_fk
```

My first attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM cart_item ci
LEFT JOIN cart c
ON ci.cart_id_fk = c.cart_id
WHERE ci.item_name = 'Apple' AND ci.item_name = 'Banana' AND ci.item_name = 'Carrot'
GROUP BY c.cart_id_pk
```

That won't work because each row in the select contains only one cart_item.

My second attempt:

```
WHERE ci.item_name = 'Apple' OR ci.item_name = 'Banana' OR ci.item_name = 'Carrot'
```

That won't work either because it will return carts containing at least one of any of those cart_items.

Tinkering with sub queries right now.. not sure if I'm on the right track.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have

```
WHERE c.cart_id_pk IN (
    SELECT ci.cart_id_fk 
    FROM cart_item ci 
    WHERE ci.item_name = "Apple")
AND c.cart_id_pk IN (
    SELECT ci.cart_id_fk 
    FROM cart_item ci 
    WHERE ci.item_name = "Banana")
AND c.cart_id_pk IN (
    SELECT ci.cart_id_fk 
    FROM cart_item ci 
    WHERE ci.item_name = "Carrot")
```

as `WHERE` statement...

This should work.

Comment: If you need more or less than than exactly 3 rows I would write a bit of dynamic SQL to iterate the where clause out by the incoming parameters.

Comment: This approach works great. Your example is a tad off, ci.cart_id_pk before IN is suppose to be ci.cart_id_fk or c.cart_id_pk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `COUNT(*)` clause to count the matching items in a subquery, as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   cart c
WHERE  cart_id IN (SELECT    cart_id_fk
                   FROM      cart_item
                   WHERE     item_name IN ('Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot')
                   GROUP BY  cart_id_fk
                   HAVING    COUNT(*) = 3 /* number of matching items*/ )
```

Note: This solution assumes that the same cart can't have multiple apples. Not sure this is OK according to the OP.

Comment: There will not be multiple apples. I ran this query but it never finished, I interrupted the execution after a couple minutes. I ran Amber's query, it successfully executed in less than one second. Could the count function be causing performance issues? There are about 20,000 records in my cart table and 40,000 in the items table.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` in the `HAVING` clause is probably a bad idea performance-wise. I wonder if changing it to `EXISTS` semantics instead of `IN` would make a difference...